# I got the error while uploading image in mongodb Cannot read property 'buffer' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

When I upload the pdf using multer in mongodb in node js then I got error "Cannot read property 'buffer' of undefined".I am trying to upload the pdf file in database.Please help to resolve this issue.Thanks in advance.

```
const express=require('express');
const multer=require('multer');
const getstream = require('get-stream');
const resume=require('../model/Resume')

const router = new express.Router();
const uplaod = multer({

    limits:{
      fileSize: 100000
    },

    fileFilter(req,file,cb)
    {
      if(!file.originalname.endsWith('pdf'))
      {
        return cb(new Error('Upload the pdf file'))
      }

      cb(undefined,true);
    }
  });
router.post('/Resume',uplaod.single('avatar'),async (req,res)=>{


     req.resume.avatar=req.file.buffer
      await req.resume.save();
      res.send({sucess:'sucess'});
    },(error,req,res,next)=>{

      //It is used for print message otherwise it will give long html message

      res.status(404).send({error:error.message});
    })



  module.exports=router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`req.file` does not exist, that's why you got this error

I think it should be `req.files.file.buffer`

if not, try to `console.log(req)`, and trace it to find the `file`

if there is no `files` or `file` in the `req` object, then the `file` hasn't been sent to the `request`